# Where can I find the name to add when creating a remote repo(github)

Tags: github, visual-studio-code, git-remote

I learn git with Vcode and dont understand how to enable to "push" to GitHub

I created a new empty repo in GitHub like

https://github.com/xxxx/testRepo.git

and in Vcode I select "push" and it ask if want to set up a new remote and I select yes and chose GitHub. A list drops down with all my GitHub projects and I select the testRepo.git.

It then ask my for a "remote name".
I read in the docs that the name defaults to "origin"(the location you cloned from) but origin is my code locally and if I write the name "origin" (the only name that works), VCode then ask me to

'
[image]

At this point I press Cancel and ask this question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default there will not be any remote branch on a newly created repo. When you clone an empty repository, it generally automatically creates a master branch that tracks origin/master (locally). So when you do an initial push it asks you to setup a remote branch to track your local branch which is master in this case.

> You can go ahead publish the changes, it is going to create a branch
> named **master** in the remote repository

Comment: Thanks but if I go ahead and publish the changes then  I will see "origin" as the name of the remote GitHub testRepo. but I never cloned it. Should it not be name "remote", but now it looks like this: ` origin  github.com/xxxx/testRepo(fetch)
origin  github.com/xxxx/testRepo (push)`

Comment: "it ask if want to set up a new remote and I select yes and chose GitHub." This is basically vscode cloning the repo for you. by default it would be named master branch. if you want to named something then you can git checkout -b <branch-name>

Comment: if it helped, please upvote and approve the answer so that it helps other people